# Features Vectors in embedding space

Tags: python, word2vec, similarity, distance, embeddings

I have a bunch of users, each of them with about 100 features.
My goal is to create an embedded space to compute the "distance" between users.
Also, I want to be able to visualize it with Tensorboard (look this example with Word2Vec http://projector.tensorflow.org/)

However, I only find example and articles about NLP, whilst my I am not dealing with sparse matrix or "vocabulary sizes".

Since I am new to this problem, could you suggest some approaches and some papers/articles/tutorial I can start with?

Comment: I insist you to opt for autoencoders. They can reduce the 100 dimensional vector to 3 dimensions where you can visualize these vectors in Tensorboard.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal could you point me to some example/code for an autoencoder used in similar context?